# How to redirect the taxonomy menu link to view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I created a Vocabulary

```
Vocabulary 1
- Term 1.1
-- Term 1.1.1 (url : autogenerate)
-- Term 1.1.2 (url : autogenerate)
```

and 2 views (view 1 and view 1)

I want to link Term 1.1.1 to view 1 and Term 1.1.2 to view 2.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Used following module.

http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display

1) Create a taxonomy

2) Go to Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata >> list

3) Search the taxonomy name at Alias (e.g restaurants/NY).

4) copy text from system column (e.g taxonomy/term/3)

Important : the url of taxonomy >> vocabulary >> term should be same with Alias of above.

5) create a view.

6) place the "taxonomy/term/3" at Page Setting >> Path

7) save

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 7 you can use either one of the following modules

- Taxonomy display - http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display

  - create a view of your liking
  - check "taxonomy term page" and save in admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/VOCABULARY/overview/display
  - and then goto the "taxonomy term page" mode in admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/VOCABULARY/overview/display/full and there is options about which view to display and many other options
- Taxonomy Views Integrator - https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi

  - create a view of your liking
  - edit each of your terms
  - click "Enable taxonomy views integrator to override presentation."
  - choose the view you have create with options for view display and some minor options

For drupal 8 only the 2nd module is available as of today.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: Well I think if the pages over at the other end of these links dissapear my answer will become useless anyway but I will try to summarize what it is those 2 modules do